# Rails Unpermitted Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a form that has some prebuilt tags that the user can select on a post.  These tags are set up with a `has_many through:` relationship.  Everything seems to be working but when I save (the post does save) there is an `Unpermitted parameter: :tags` from the controller's save method.

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, through: :post_tags
end
```

PostTag model:

```
class PostTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :post_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :post_tags
```

Post controller methods:

```
  def update
      # saves tags
      save_tags(@post, params[:post][:tags])

      # updates params (not sure if this is required but I thought that updating the tags might be causing problems for the save.
      params[:post][:tags] = @post.tags
      if @post.update(post_params)
        ... 
    end
  end

...

private 
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :notes, tags: [])
  end

  def save_tags(post, tags)
    tags.each do |tag|
       # tag.to_i, is because the form loads tags as just the tag id.
       post.post_tags.build(tag: Tag.find_by(id: tag.to_i))
    end
  end
```

View (tags are checkboxes displayed as buttons):

```
  <%= form.label :tags %>
    <div class="box">
    <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
      <div class="check-btn">
        <label>
          <%=  check_box_tag('dinner[tags][]', tag.id) %><span> <%= tag.name %></span>
      </label>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Again this saves, and works fine, but I'd like to get rid of the `Unpermitted parameter` that is thrown in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your whole solution is creative but extremely redundant. Instead use the collection helpers:

```
<%= form_with(model: @post) |f| %> 
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

`tags_ids=` is a special setter created by `has_many :tags, through: :post_tags` (they are created for all has_many and HABTM assocations). It takes an array of ids and will automatically create/delete join rows for you.

All you have to do in your controller is whitelist `post[tag_ids]` as an array:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save 
      redirect_to @post 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post 
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 
  # ...

  def post_params
    params.require(:post)
          .permit(:name, :notes, tag_ids: [])
  end
end
```